# How to conditionally add an AND condition to a WHERE clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following schema:

```
| ID | BUNDLE_ID | IS_ADMIN |
```

I need to select data from the above table having an AND clause on the basis of certain criteria, i.e

```
IF @FLAG = 1
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE A 
    WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN (3, 5)
ELSE
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE A 
    WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN (1, 2)
```

Can I achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 6):

General approach is to rewrite the query with a boolean expression that evaluates to what you need based on flag's value:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND ( -- Common part ...
    (@Flag=1  AND BUNDLE_ID IN(3,5))     -- IF   ...
OR
    (@Flag<>1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN(1,2))     -- ELSE ...
)
```

Comment: From an execution plan perspective, would this still be "clean"? *(If it was searching different fields, for example, I'd say that using IF would be "better".)*

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is simple.

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE A
WHERE (A.IS_ADMIN = 1
        AND BUNDLE_ID IN (3,5)
        AND @FLAG = 1)
    OR (A.IS_ADMIN = 1
        AND BUNDLE_ID IN (1,2)
        AND (@FLAG <> 1 OR @FLAG IS NULL))
```

Comment: one bracket at the end is missing.

Comment: @ NiveaGM, Thanks - I have updated the answer to add the bracket

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives, just because...

```
SELECT * FROM a_table A WHERE @flag =  1 AND IS_ADMIN = 1 AND A.BUNDLE_ID IN (3, 5)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM a_table A WHERE @flag <> 1 AND IS_ADMIN = 1 AND A.BUNDLE_ID IN (1, 2)
```

Should give a similar execution plan to...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a_table   AS A
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT A.BUNDLE_ID WHERE @flag =  1 AND A.BUNDLE_ID IN (3, 5)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT A.BUNDLE_ID WHERE @flag <> 1 AND A.BUNDLE_ID IN (1, 2)
)
WHERE
  A.IS_ADMIN = 1
```

A different layout from others answers already provided, but providing the same logic...

```
WITH
    admin AS
(
    SELECT * FROM a_table A WHERE IS_ADMIN = 1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    admin
WHERE
       (@flag =  1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN (3, 5))
    OR (@flag <> 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN (1, 2))
```

Comment: I like alternatives. But you should consider the fact that `@FLAG` could possibly be NULL

Comment: @HoneyBadger - That would be very complete, I agree, but beyond the scope of what I was trying to communicate ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE A 
WHERE  (A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN(3,5) AND @FLAG = 1)
   OR  (A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN(1,2) AND (@FLAG <> 1 OR @FLAG IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use table driven control

```
SELECT A.* FROM TABLE A 
    INNER JOIN (VALUES (0,1),(0,2),(1,3),(1,5)) COND(FLAG,BUNDLE_ID)  
        ON A.BUNDLE_ID = COND.BUNDLE_ID
            AND COND.FLAG = ISNULL(@FLAG,0)
WHERE
    A.IS_ADMIN = 1
```

Comment: Putting where with OR will be better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly valid syntax too...

```
IF @FLAG = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN(3,5)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND BUNDLE_ID IN(1,2)
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A 
WHERE A.IS_ADMIN = 1 AND 
(BUNDLE_ID IN (3,5) AND @FLAG = 1) OR 
(BUNDLE_ID IN (1,2) AND @FLAG <> 1)
```

Comment: Operator precedence warning :)